# How to retrieve the rows (with maximum value in a field) having a another common field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I have a table; let it be called `table1`; with the following fields and data

[alt text http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3827/45939084.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3827/45939084.png)

I need a query that returns the record with the maximum value in `Field3` for each group of records having the same value in `Field2`. So that the query returns:

[alt text http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/62/48847706.png](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/62/48847706.png)

How could this be done using SQL queries ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field2 ORDER BY field3 DESC) AS rn
        FROM    table1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT  q.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT field2
        FROM    table1
        ) qo
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    table1 t
        WHERE   t.field2 = qo.field2
        ORDER BY
                t.field3 DESC
        ) q
```

Depending on the `field2` cardinality, the first or the second query can be more efficient.

See this article for more details:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. The first one returns an extra "rn" column, please edit it as follows: ...... WITH q AS (SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field2 ORDER BY field3 DESC) AS rn FROM table1) SELECT  Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 FROM q WHERE rn = 1 ......  but the second is great, also the article is great. Many thanks.